# How to use the phone call task for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use the `PhoneCallTask` in a Windows Phone 8 app, but am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
private PhoneCallTask phoneTask = new PhoneCallTask();
private void btnServiceClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if (txtServiceClientNo.Text.Length > 0)
      {
         phoneTask.PhoneNumber = txtServiceClientNo.Text;
         phoneTask.Show();
      }

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which error are you getting? Maybe you have forgotten to include `ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER` to your WMAppManifest?

Comment: good..thank you jlahd

Answer (score 6):

First check if you are including the Phone Dialer capability in your WMAppManifest.xml file, and if not, add this to the `Capabilities` section:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
```

Comment: @Kanniyappan http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/asking-upvote-for-accepted-answer go with links.